# use python's pandas to treat aws dynamodb data

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, amazon-dynamodb

I'm getting data from a dynamodb table, using boto3 for python 2.7 and I would use pandas to group by and sort the data.

Unfortunately the dynamodb data format is quite a bit tricky. Like this:

```
data = [{
      u 'permaname': {
        u 'S': u 'facebook'
      },
      u 'uuid': {
        u 'S': u '4b873085-c995-4ce4-9325-cfc70fcd4040'
      },
      u 'tags': {
        u 'L': []
      },
      u 'type': {
        u 'S': u 'xxxxxx'
      },
      u 'createdOn': {
        u 'N': u '1502099627'
      },
      u 'source': {
        u 'S': u 'xxxxxxx'
      },
      u 'data': {
        u 'NULL': True
      },
      u 'crawler': {
        u 'S': u 'xxxxxxx'
      }
    }, {
      u 'permaname': {
        u 'S': u 'facebook'
      },
      u 'uuid': {
        u 'S': u '25381aef-a7db-4b79-b599-89fd060fcf73'
      },
      u 'tags': {
        u 'L': []
      },
      u 'type': {
        u 'S': u 'xxxxxxx'
      },
      u 'createdOn': {
        u 'N': u '1502096901'
      },
      u 'source': {
        u 'S': u 'xxxxxxx'
      },
      u 'data': {
        u 'NULL': True
      },
      u 'crawler': {
        u 'S': u 'xxxxxxx'
      }
    }]
```

To do my group by and sort stuffs I must create a pandas object and I can not figure out how to do.

This is how I'm trying:

```
obj = pandas.DataFrame(data)
print list(obj.sort_values(['createdOn'],ascending=False).groupby('source'))
```

If I print obj like this:

```
print list(obj)
```

I have :

> [u'crawler', u'createdOn', u'data', u'permaname', u'source', u'tags',
>   u'type', u'uuid']

Does someone know how to create the dataFrame obj with the dynamodb data ?

Comment: You can use pandas.json_normalize

Answer (score 4):

I am going to try to answer in Python 3.

```
data = [{
       'permaname': {
         'S':  'facebook'
      },
       'uuid': {
         'S':  '4b873085-c995-4ce4-9325-cfc70fcd4040'
      },
       'tags': {
         'L': []
      },
       'type': {
         'S':  'xxxxxx'
      },
       'createdOn': {
         'N':  '1502099627'
      },
       'source': {
         'S':  'xxxxxxx'
      },
       'data': {
         'NULL': True
      },
       'crawler': {
         'S':  'xxxxxxx'
      }
    }, {
       'permaname': {
         'S':  'facebook'
      },
       'uuid': {
         'S':  '25381aef-a7db-4b79-b599-89fd060fcf73'
      },
     'tags': {
         'L': []
      },
       'type': {
         'S':  'xxxxxxx'
      },
       'createdOn': {
         'N':  '1502096901'
      },
       'source': {
         'S':  'xxxxxxx'
      },
       'data': {
         'NULL': True
      },
       'crawler': {
         'S':  'xxxxxxx'
      }
    }]
```

Using dynamodb_json as previously suggested.

```
from dynamodb_json import json_util as json
obj = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(data))
obj
```

With output:

```
    crawler     createdOn   data    permaname   source  tags    type    uuid
0   xxxxxxx     1502099627  None    facebook    xxxxxxx     []  xxxxxx  4b873085-c995-4ce4-9325-cfc70fcd4040
1   xxxxxxx     1502096901  None    facebook    xxxxxxx     []  xxxxxxx     25381aef-a7db-4b79-b599-89fd060fcf73
```

Grouping by (I use max() to aggregate results)

```
obj.sort_values(['createdOn'],ascending=False).groupby('source').max()
```

With output

```
       crawler  createdOn   data    permaname   tags    type    uuid
source                          
xxxxxxx     xxxxxxx     1502099627  NaN     facebook    []  xxxxxxx     4b873085-c995-4ce4-9325-cfc70fcd4040
```

Printig the list

```
print(list(obj))
```

Output:

```
[u'crawler', u'createdOn', u'data', u'permaname', u'source', u'tags', u'type', u'uuid']
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

To convert the dynamodb json to regular json you can use this library:

https://github.com/Alonreznik/dynamodb-json

Answer (score 0):

The dynamodb-json library above seems to be broken for me. Utilizing Pandas and Python3, with the code below were able to convert to excel format.

```
file_name = 'filename.json'
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
db = pd.DataFrame()
for line in data:
    item = json.loads(line)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(item['Item'])
    df_head = df.columns.to_list()
    db_head = db.columns.to_list()
    head = list(set(df_head + db_head))
    db = pd.DataFrame(db, columns=head)
    db = pd.concat([db, df], ignore_index=True)
print(db)
file_path = os.path.dirname(file_name)
file_name = os.path.basename(file_name)
file_name = file_name.replace('.json', '.xlsx')
file_path = f"{file_path}\\{file_name}"
db.to_excel(file_path, index=False)
```

This required the pandas and openpyxl libraries. For other formats, this should convert to them just fine like dictionaries, lists etc.

Comment: Do see that your answer exacly adhere to the question. For example, there was never a mention of Excel. You are not using the input that was provided for [mre]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35186549)